# Using NETSH command with variables through batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, netsh

I am unable to find a way to create a dynamic batch file for **NETSH** commands.

I have created static files to give IP and DNS address(es).

I want to know how do I enable user input and put those values in the succeeding command?

For example:

> netsh interface set interface name=**Ethernet** admin=disabled

How do I create a variable which user will assign a value to and enforce that variable at place of **ethernet**?

Example 2:

> netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Wi-Fi" static **10.0.0.159 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1**

How do I do same for multiple values such as those highlighted?

Comment: Take a look at `SET /P`.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `set /?` to get output the help of this command explaining `set /P` syntax (P for Prompt) like `set /P "InternfaceName=Enter interface name: "` used with `netsh interface set interface "name=%InterfaceName%" admin=disabled`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have thought of set as an independent command. I did not realize that when I was searching for a solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask the user for input use this:

```
set /p "UserInput1=Please input parameters for the program​: "
```

To refer to their input use this:

```
%UserInput1%
```

The %UserInput1% will get replaced with whatever the user typed in. Please note if they type in any "&" or "|" symbols the command prompt will think that anything after that symbol is a command and will mess up. This usually won't matter though as these symbols most likely wouldn't be typed in anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and respond back.

Comment: Thank you for providing the correct syntax and answer.